# Multi-year analysis of points at the same location

Tags: qgis, point, vector, analysis, multi-criteria-analysis

I want to do a multi-year analysis in QGIS. One of my clients would like a map indicating the overall mean for his Yield Data going over 10 years.

I have my 10 years points separate. How do I combine all 10 years in order to get 1 surface indicating the overall mean for 10 years? (For example, for 10 years his overall Yield was 10 tons). I would like to show this in contour form and not pixels.

I read up about the Multi Criteria Analysis, but I am not sure if this is indeed the tool I need. This tool seems a little hectic for what I want to do.

Comment: What format is your data in?

Comment: Are the points on top of eachother for each year, or spread out? Can you add a screenshot

Comment: Hi, I think you are asking 2 questions: 1) how to merge your data into a single point and 2) how to vizualize a mean of your data in a spatialy continuouse way. Is this correct? If so reformulating your question into 2 seperate questions would certainly help to get an asnwer.